# Cannot access shell variable from python script

Tags: macos, python-2.7, shell, terminal

I am using OSX terminal and Python 2.7

My shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter the name of the file
read fileName
python gulp.py
```

My python script:

```
import os                       #import vars
try:
    print os.environ["fileName"]    #print imported var
except KeyError:
    print "Please set the environment variable" 
fileTitle=fileName + '.inp'
f=open('fileTitle', 'r')
line=f.readlines()
print line[0]
```

I tried with no positive results:

```
 import sys
var1=sys.arg[1]
```

and

```
import os
os.getenv["fileName"]
```

The shell and python scripts are in the same folder

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The single quotes around the filename in `f=open('fileTitle', 'r')` makes open the literal filename `fileTitle`, not the variable `fileTitle` which contains the value you were looking for. Change it to `f=open(fileTitle, 'r')`. This is of course in addition to setting the os env available to the child process via export or cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable needs to be marked for `export` in the shell, otherwise it will not be passed to other programs:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter the name of the file
read fileName
export fileName
python gulp.py
```

Things to note:

- The `export` can go anywhere as long as it's run before `python`. It doesn't have to be after the variable is assigned.
- Using lowercase variable names in bash (like you're doing) is a great habit that prevents bugs. Exported variables are conventionally uppercase though. You can have both by exporting another name with that value:  `export FILENAME="$fileName"` or using prefix assignments: `FILENAME="$fileName" python gulp.py`

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I did not find that solution